# How to display label only in the selected cell of a TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view. I've added a label named "lbl1" to the cells. And i implemented "heightForRowAtIndexPath" method. And Iam increasing height of selected row using

```
[tblView beginUpdates];
[tblView endUpdates];
```

then i'm adding a label "lbl2" to the cell in the extended area and this label should be visible in the selected cell only.

Here "lbl2" is displaying in the background even though the particular cell is not selected.It is looking like overwriting "lbl1".

is there any way to get the right output?

Comment: Little more code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert the label in the selected cell, insert it in the `didselectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //increase the cell height and then do the following:
    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    *lbl2.text = @"Some text";
    [currentCell addSubview:lbl2]; //remember to position the label properly.        
}
```

Hope this would be the solution you are looking for.

**EDIT**
If you want to remove the label when another row is selected, save the previously selected row's indexPath and next time remove the label, decrease, update the height then set the selected indexPath to the variable and then update the current one. Like in the code below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cpreviousCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousIndexPath];
    //remove lbl2 and decrease the height of the cell if required
    UITableViewCell *currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //increase the cell height and then do the following:
    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    *lbl2.text = @"Some text";
    [currentCell addSubview:lbl2]; //remember to position the label properly.
    //and finally set the indexPath
    previousIndexPath = indexPath;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep a reference to the previously selected indexPath and then reload both the indexPath of the selected cell, and the indexPath of the newly selected cell.

This is (I think) better than holding on to the cell itself, especially to avoid re-selecting. 
Since the TableView scrolls, comparing two cells to avoid re-selecting could fail, whereas comparing indexPath.row will alwyas be fine.

so you want to hold on to the indexPath, and if there is a change call :

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:prevIndexPath,newIndexPath,nil]; 
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Of course, the actual label adding/removing should be done in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.